# Floquet Multipliers

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I'm beginning to look into stability analysis of limit cycles. Whilst looking through a limit cycle continuation I noticed that one of the Floquet multipliers was staying at value 1 throughout. When I tried to read around to find a reason why I came across the following sentence: "Among the Floquet multipliers there is always one equal to unity, which reflects neutral stability to a shift along the periodic orbit.”

I don't fully understand this sentence or how it might relate to my 5-dimensional system, in which I'm interested in periodic behaviour of one of the state variables. What is the significance of having 5 multipliers, with one of them constant at 1 as the limit cycle is continued? I have a loose idea of what the Floquet multipliers are, but not the nuance of how they're derived.

Comment: In two sentences: the moduli of the Floquet exponents (besides that one equal to unity!) indicate the rate of growth of vectors under the linearization of the Poincaré map. If their moduli are less than one, the periodic orbit is (orbitally) asymptotically stable.

Answer (score 3):

It is as is said in your quote, if $\phi(t;x_0)$ is the flow of $\dot x=f(x)$, the solution with $\phi(0;x_0)=x_0$, then the situation with a periodic solution is that $\phi(T;x_0)=x_0$ for $T>0$. By the transitivity of the flow, also $$\phi(T;\phi(s;x_0))=\phi(T+s;x_0)=\phi(s;x_0).$$ The Floquet multipliers characterize the linearization of the map $x\mapsto \phi(T;x)$ for $x\approx x_0$, and for $x=\phi(s;x_0)$, $s\approx 0$, you get the identity, thus the eigenvalue $1$ with eigenvector $v=f(x_0)$ in the linearization.